# Xcode how to connect view to view using button ? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, keyboard

I'm making a custom keyboard using swift on Xcode.

I have created some views(xib files) which are of keyboards.
and I wanna connect these views each other like when I press [123]button, the view changes to the numeric one so I can type numbers :)

Actually I finished globe button(which is next keyboard button which is auto-created when I added custom keyboard target) but can't understand the codes ;-;

**What I want to do is to connect button(as an IBOutlet or IBAction) with view(xib)**

Comment: Could you please share the code

Comment: Check my answer. If still any problem then let me know.@Yumin Hwang

Answer (score 0):

Take two views in xib or storyboard and IBOutlet them. One view has the buttons for alphabets and other view has buttons for numbers.

You have to do code something like below :

```
 @IBOutlet var alphabelView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet var numericView: UIView!
 @IBOutlet var toggleBtn: UIButton!
 btn.setTitle("ABC", forState: .Normal)
 btn.setTitle("123", forState: .Selected)
 toggleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.toggleButtonsClicked(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Numeric view will be hidden initially. When user press on **123** do code like below lines of code:

```
 func toggleButtonsClicked(button: UIButton) {
        button.selected = !butto.selected
        alphabelView.hidden = true
        numericView.hidden = false
    }
```

Comment: can i ask one more? how to connect buttons ??

Comment: Which buttons you want to connect?

Comment: 123 button and ABC button . so when i press these button it will be connected to another keyboard view right ?? :o

Comment: I tried;-; when i press 123 button, it goes to the default keyboard that simulator provides. and i have separated two button which are 123 button and ABC button on each view so didn't set the title. is it matter??

Comment: There will be one button not 2. That one button has title "ABC" when not selected and when it is selected it has title "123".
My advise to you is that first understand any sample code of custom keyboard.